# What happens with ActiveMQ unacknowledged messages

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, consumer

If there's a queue created in ActiveMQ which has one producer (which is client acknowledged mode) and one listener in whose onMessage method after successful processing of message only it is acknowledged. Say if there is an exception and the message remains unacknowledged and hence remains in the queue. Will it be sent again to consumer? Or what happens to such messages?

Comment: What kind of client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

All unacknowledged messages remain in the queue.

> Will it be sent again to consumer?

Yes, it will be sent to consumer again.

I am not sure if Active MQ has a queue property which when set will stop delivering the same message to consumer again and again and instead move it to a queue called backout queue or a dead letter queue. IBM MQ has a property on queue, `BOTHRESH` - Backout Threshold - Every time a message is delivered to consumer, the delivery count (or Backout Count) is incremented. When the message is being delivered again, `IBM MQ` will check if the backout count of the message is more than `BOTHRESH` count. If so the message is moved to a backout queue if one is set or to a dead letter queue.

Comment: And how to access such messages ? In IBM MQ? I will check for activemq now that I know it gets delivered again. I am curious about accessing messages sent to backup queues in IBM MQ

Comment: Backout Queue is just another queue and accessing messages from that queue is also same as with other queues.

Answer (score 0):

When the message is not processed by the consumer due to some exception, then it's good to send negative acknowledgement. For example NACK with STOMP protocol. The message then remains in the queue. ActiveMQ can be configured to make redelivery attempts up on receiving NACK from consumer.

https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#NACK

Comment: I have used session.recover(). Even that keeps the message in pending status and it gets sent first before other messages.

Comment: This answer is also right. But, in my case I am not using stomp.

Comment: In general, when the message remains in the queue because of un-acknowledgement, it'll be sent again to the consumer as any other message. In ActiveMQ , by default, there will be some 6 re-delivery attempts to the consumer, before it is sent to dlq.